# Android align text top center

Tags: android, gravity

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but i couldn't find anything that was quite what I'm looking for. Basically, i want to align the text in the text View to be in the top center. And I would like to do this in XML if possible. So i want to combine

```
android:gravity="center"
```

and

```
android:gravity="top"
```

so that it aligns it with both. I have already tried to put both attributes in the text View element but it just gives an error.

Comment: Please post the error and all other relevant information

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, you cannot duplicate the attribute, though you can combine values.

```
android:gravity="g1|g2"
```

However, `center` implies *both vertical and horizontal centering* so `top|center` wouldn't be correct. You should use

```
android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: But when I tried on android studio. Just "top|center" is good, too. Guess they have same effect on TextView implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply more than one propery to gravity you must use `|` like this

```
android:gravity="top|center"
```

Answer (score 1):

use a RelativeLayout as your ViewGroup and do this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDemo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to your textview and it will center and top to layout:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```