# Android align a text at the top center fails

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried aligining a text at the topcenter but fails

I have checked on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684050/android-align-text-top-center) but the answer fails

I have tried

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".OnboardingActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Welcome"
    />
```

THis is what am getting after running on the emulator which is not centered

[image]

Comment: please specify what you want to achive

Comment: @KevinKurien i want this centered horizontally but at the top

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI than use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in your `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i see the i forgot to make width match parent

Comment: i dont know who downvoted but this is the correct answer

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Yes and gravity only works in linear layout.. relative layout have their own tags

Answer (score 1):

add this in your `RelativeLayout`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`** in your **`TextView`**

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OnboardingActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Welcome"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i want this to be at the top center not center in the screen

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI can u share your expected output as image

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI and also it will set your textview in Top|Center position in screen check i have added both `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

another solution to add this to your TextView:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```